# Como extrair valor específico de mensagem recebida via Websocket?

Tags: python, json, string, api, websocket

Eu estou tentando extrair o "balance" de um JSON.
Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer isso de maneira direta, sem receber essa mensagem completa, que acaba sendo gigante, mas sim extrair apenas o valor que eu quero.

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({"authorize": "Vn55jnImK7UzcYr"}) # valor apenas de exemplo
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('Dados: %s' % message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

A impressão na IDLE fica conforme imagem abaixo que eu cortei devido os dados, mas gostaria de extrair esse valor de balance. Pra isso eu teria que manipular a string? O problema de manipular a string pegando as posições específicas, é que este valor pode ir de 0 a 999999... Então a posição sempre mudaria.
Ou tem alguma forma de receber diretamente este valor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tiver certeza que o JSON está bem montado, taransforme ele num dicionário

### Primeira forma (eval)

```
>>> texto = '{"codigo": 123, "balance": 10.20, "outro": "qualquer coisa"}'

>>> dict_texto = eval(texto)

>>> dict_texto
{'codigo': 123, 'balance': 10.2, 'outro': 'qualquer coisa'}

>>> dict_texto["balance"]
10.2
```

### Segunda forma (módulo json)

```
>>> import json

>>> dict_texto2 = json.loads(texto)

>>> dict_texto2
{'codigo': 123, 'balance': 10.2, 'outro': 'qualquer coisa'}

>>> dict_texto2["balance"]
10.2
```

**Nota**: A segunda é bem melhor, porque o `eval` pode sofrer com códigos maliciosos.

Comment: Ela fecha "]" antes de "balance", então quando faço o json.loads, ela não imprime nada. a = message b = json.loads(a) print(b['balance'])

Comment: não consegui ver o json direito, mas parece que seria `b["authorize"]["balance"]`

Comment: Perfeito! Deu certo, muito obrigado @Paulo Marques.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é usar regex:

```py
import re

result='"balance":10175.95, "country":"br","currency":"USD", "balance":33.52, "country":"br","currency":"USD"'

valores= re.findall(r'(?<!"balance")\d+\.\d{2}',result)

for valor in valores:
    print(valor)
```

Retorna:

```
10175.95
33.52
```

Para uma string co

Comment: Tentei fazer assim 
    a = message
    b = json.loads(a)
    print(b['balance'])
Mas não imprimiu nada

Comment: Dessa maneira que você colocou deu muito certo. Só uma dúvida, teria como extrair somente o número sem isso [' ']? Ou ainda vou ter que manipular a string?

Comment: É uma lista. Então você pode iterar sobre ela. Vou editar a resposta. De todo modo, olhe a resposta do @Paulo Marques que apresentou uma solução mais simples.